# change timezone of jquery calendar plugin

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using this plugin [Jquery FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) . It showing the time in specific timezone. How can i show the timezone of calendar to the user and also to change from one timezone to another.I wants to display the user what timezone he is using,in calendar section.

Also when i am using input field in calendar it showin time in time in this format `Tue Jul 09 2013 17:44:32 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` i wants to show in format like 'Y-m-d H:ia'

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Here they given some time format ..http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/timeFormat/

Comment: And the last line  http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/utilities/formatDate_pre_13/

Comment: Can you show how you are passing options ?

Comment: Will this help? http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/ignoreTimezone/

Comment: @DevlshOne i wants to show timezone to the user in calendar and a link show that he can able to change that timezone in future. what is the use of this in that arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/ignoreTimezone.

Comment: @KumariManisha No idea. I've been using FullCalendar for a couple of years and have never seen a way to change timezones. I would get with the author.

Comment: @Baadshah i wants to display/change timezone not the datetime